# How can I see if SQL Server 2008 is the R2 release?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, version

Question says it all.
Is there a way I can see what version of SQL 2008 is installed?
It's either the SQL 2008 enterprise edition or SQL 2008 R2 enterprise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```

Should be 10.5xxxxx for R2. It is 10.0xxxx for "plain" SQL Server 2008

For edition: `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Edition')`. [SERVERPROPERTY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx) gives you quite a lot

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to it using management studio, it shows the server name and version. 2008 is 10.0.1600, 2008 R2 is 10.50.1600.